# Do I need a MSDN subscription

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msdn

I'm thinking about buying Visual Studio Pro with MSDN, but I'm not sure if I would really need MSND access. I've never dealt with MSDN so I have a couple of questions. I mainly want to develop apps for Windows 8, 8.1 and 7, and I just can't see what exactly I will get out of a MSDN subscription.

What are the greatest advantages that it offers? I know about being able to download many software at my subscription level, but I don't really need it. Doesn't visual studio provide a way to test your software on many WIN-RT, Win 8 devices so you don't have to download and install all the different operating systems on your own system?

Maybe there is something here I haven't figured out? Can you guys tell me how beneficial has been to have a MSDN subscription for you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well see here for the advantages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/subscriptions/aa718661.aspx or do a quick research.

Personally since Microsoft tends to change their release cycle, especially for Visual Studio (as 2013 version is soon available, and I guess 2014 is planned already) the benefit of MSDN is clearly at hand.

Since I am willing to use the new VS features MSDN is quite fine.

But this depends on your budget and whether you are going to switch to the latest VS

Comment: So as soon as I have an msdn subscription I get every release of visual studio for free?

Comment: Yes, as long you are a subscriber you can download and use every Visual Studio.  (Not sure: After MSDN expires you are still allowed to use the versions you have obtained but you have no longer access to the download portal)

Answer (score 1):

If you tend to use a single VS version for multiple years (I certainly don't want to deal with the upgrade trouble every year) then without MSDN is fine.
It's hard to find it, but the 2013 version with MSDN for example is at http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/mseea/en_US/pdp/Visual-Studio-Professional-2013/productID.288483200

Comment: You get much more than just the latest vs version, you also can install as many OS instances for development or test version as you want.